# Icons not showing in my wordpress/bootstrap theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, siteorigin

I am trying to get icons in several places to show without luck. I do see them in my previews (from siteorigin's pagebuilder previews) but after publishing the site I dont see the icons anymore.

a link to the site:
http://jobdashboard.net/vivaink/feverscout/

if you scroll down to "See Full Features and Specs" that is supposed to be an accordion widget

here is the source code:

```
<span class="iw-so-tgl-open"><span class="sow-icon-fontawesome" data-sow-icon="" style="font-size: 2em; color: right"></span></span>

<span class="sow-icon-fontawesome" data-sow-icon="" style="font-size: 2em; color: right"></span>
```

both open and close states have a weird rectangular data-sow-icon value in them

Any suggestions?

Comment: I cant see "See Full Features and Specs"

Comment: Hi vel! look for this area of the site [link] (http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1464359/78793e6a13306f803cede704d8200e6a)

Comment: we cannot check the issue in image. can you post the code? or create test account if you can

Comment: I looked at the website just now. It seems like the accordion effect is working now. Could you share what the problem was? Please note that it is acceptable to answer your own questions ;-)

Comment: I am having a similar problem, although the icons do show most of the time, especially after a reload. I am using a tabbed widget with icons in the tabs' titles. I also included the page on the front page of my WP Twenty-Seventeen theme - there, the icon problem occurs a lot more often than when I look at the actual page.. is it necessary to include/require the icon-set somewhere?